# showing f is polynomial when $|f(z)| \geq C|z|^N$ if $|z|>R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function that satisfies an estimate of the form $|f(z)| \geq C|z|^N$ if $|z|>R$ for some positive integer $N$ and positive real constants $c$ and $R$. Prove that $f$ must be a polynomial.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For a hint, check here: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~bell/MA530/Lectures/lec23.pdf

Comment: are you sure of the sign on the inequality in $|f(z)\geq C|z|^{N}$? i think it should be $\leq$

Comment: @Basti yes, I am pretty sure the sign is correct. The degree of the polynomial will be at least N, I think.

Comment: @Basti: The result would be true in the other case, but instead of using Casorati---Weierstrass or Picard one would use Cauchy's estimate perhaps to show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$.  In this case, we would be able to say the degree is at least $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that an entire function $f$ is not a polynpoial, so $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$.  If $f$ satisfies $|f(z)| \geq C|z|^N$ $(|z|>R)$, then $f(z)\neq \alpha $ for every $\alpha $ with $|\alpha |<CR^N$ in $|z|>R$. This violates the Picard's theorem and hence $f$ must be a polynomial.